# How to use getopt in c regardless of position

Tags: c, getopt

I am having some trouble having the get opt to identify the flag regardless of what position it's called at in the inputs in. My program takes in 4 inputs as parameters for the program to function.

here is my code

```
int a= strtol(argv[1],NULL,10);
int b = strtol(argv[2],NULL,10);
double c = strtol(argv[3],NULL,10);
double  d = strtol(argv[4],NULL,10);
```

so for example i would run my program by calling ./test 5 5 5 5 
However I need the program to recognize it regardless of position and then set the variables according to where it is positioned at. Currently I am trying to have it figure out when -p(number) is passed in. So for example ./test 5 5 5 5 -p5 or ./test p 5 5 5 5 5 it will recognize the 5 next to the p up to 1 space away and store that number

my getopt that i have right now is as follows

```
int i ;
int j = 0;
while ( (opt = getopt(argc,argv, "p:") ) != 1){
      switch(opt){
           case 'p':
               cycles = (int) strtol ( optarg, Null,10);
```

Comment: Use the `optind` variable?

Comment: `getopt` doesn't work that way. The way it works: options come first, additional arguments follow.